# How do I move Apache's www folder and then create a symbolic back link to it under Linux

Tags: linux, permissions, apache-http-server

I have installed ISPConfig and have an Apache /var/www folder.

I would like to move this www folder to another drive mounted at /data.

I did

```
cp -r /var/www /data
```

to create a copy in the /data folder

I then did

```
mv /var/www /var/wwworig
```

to create a backup of the www folder just in case

I then created a symbolic link from /var/www to /data/www

```
ln -s /data/www /var/www
```

Giving me a link from /var/www to /data/www

I have tried restarting Apache but still only receive 403 errors when browsing my page.

I have FollowSymLinks in my Apache config.
I don't want to change the directories listed in my Apache config because I don't want to get into changing ISPConfig that much. I would just like a symbolic link to another drive.

---

Here are permissions that may be pertinent.

Original /var folder

```
drwxr-xr-x 10 root   root   4096 Mar 23  2011 www
```

Original /data folder

```
drwxr-xr-x 10 root  root   4096 Oct 12 06:02 www
```

/var folder with link

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root      9 Oct 12 10:16 www -> /data/www
drwxr-xr-x 10 root   root   4096 Mar 23  2011 wwwbackup
```

Comment: Check the Apache logs in /var/www and see what the actual problem is. You might have to turn up the logging level of Apache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you copied the directory have you checked file permissions and ownership? If you copied as root user the new directory will belong to root from that point on. user nobody or httpd will not be able to reach these data.

Comment: I tried the copy again while keeping permissions cp -rp /var/www /data/www correct?
Now I'm getting a different error of 500 "The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration"

Comment: You're right keeping the permissions the same while copying got it to serve correctly. I then needed to correct my suphp.conf by removing the docroot lines.

Answer (score 0):

consider using `mount --bind olddir newdir`.

Comment: I tried that per your suggestion but received this:  
`[root@server var]# mount --bind /var/www /data/www`  
`mount: special device /var/www does not exist`  
Thank you for the suggestion though.

Comment: @Chris: does `/data/www` exists? It should. What OS are you on? Does your `man mount` say anything about `--bind` option? It works on my debian.

Comment: Your right the folder didn't exist when I tried it the first time. I had a /var/www folder and tried it again and it worked just fine. I will probably stick to the link but thanks again.

Comment: @Chris: If you found answer useful, you should up-vote it :-)